# Rotating from center rather than from left, middle

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

Im working on a system for skeletal animation and each bone's angle is based on its parent. I have to rotate that bone from the end of the parent joint for that angle to be accurate as illustrated in the first part of this illustration:

[image]

What I need to do is the second part of the illustration. This is because my drawing API only supports rotating around the center of the bitmap.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand this, but if you want to rotate around a specific point, then you would translate the entire shape by (-anchor.x, -anchor.y), then rotate, and then translate it by (anchor.x, anchor.y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the rotation with a translation.  Rotate the figure about the center, then move it to where it should be.

Comment: What would the translation be?

Comment: You'd translate downward by half the width of the image after doing a rotation.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to introduce extra blank pixels into your bitmap.  If you can only rotate around the center of the bitmap, consider what happens if you double the width of your bitmap and then translate the image you want to rotate so that it's flush up against the right.

For example, suppose your image is

```
+-------+
X image |
+-------+
```

where the X is the point you want to rotate around.  Now, construct this image:

```
+-------+-------+
| blank X image |
+-------+-------+
```

If you rotate around the center of this image, notice that you're rotating right on top of the X, which is what you wanted to do in the first place.  The resulting rotated image looks like this:

```
+---+
| b |
| l |
| a |
| n |
| k |
+-X-+
| i |
| m |
| a |
| g |
| e |
+---+
```

Now, you just extract the bottom half of the image and you've got your original image, rotate 90 degrees around the indicated X point.

Hope this helps!